# Copy Paste Script Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work for a major Motor Manufacturer and I need some help with a google sheets script that I need to write (I assume a script is the way forward?)

I have a google sheets file that is used to monitor issues and planned improvements for multiple departments. The workbook has multiple tabs that I need to somehow copy and paste data around within it.

I have included a sample file to try and help explain it, it's quite a complicated file to try and explain...I will do my best. It sounds like I need to use a script but I am new to using scripts.

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kqJseoBp_7dJvSAsTjb00D8XEhQ_ALJ978N3ENCQ03Q/edit?usp=sharing)

**Explanation of file:**
On a weekly basis I update the sheet with latest data into the "Master data" sheet, this sheet feeds the "electrical" sheet using a query.The dept owner for electrical updates updates the "electricalinput" sheet with his actions and timing and this feeds into the "electrical" sheet also. The "electrical" sheet in turn feeds the "improvement data" sheet which feeds the chart.

It is arranged like this so what when new issues are added and the order changes the comments follow on the "electrical" sheet, and the owner only needs to update the "electricalinput" sheet with comments that he hasn't already done.

**What I would like try and do:**
I would like to be able to run a script that filters or extracts anything in the electrical sheet with #N/A against it (which means the 3 cell combination hasn't been found in the input sheet) and copy and paste just those items into the "electricalinput" sheet at the next available line that isn't populated. In the actual file there are multiple depts so variations of the script will have to run to cover the different depts.

Comment: I am new to scripts, all examples of copying and pasting scripts that I have tried to adapt to the file I have struggled to get it to copy adjacent cells dependant on the condition of another cell. I am also struggling to find code that will paste the data into the next free row of a worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xlqu_HwvIida9rZMRmTJbpBjw5qr6eysKLY1NnwoXAk/edit?usp=sharing) that you shared with relevant code.
You can run the script via `Add Ons->Master Data Utils->Clean Up Keys` menu.
 The menu was created in the `OnOpen` function from this script.

Note that there are a couple of requirements as below for the script to work.(already taken care of in the shared ss)

1. Departments lists and details helpful for processing all the data as shown below.
2. There should be a `NamedRange` called `Department_List` which would be top left cell of the table shown above.

[image]

- `Column to Clean` -> `Action Summary`
  is the column we would be using to search of `#N/A`
- `Display Sheet Name` -> `Electrical`
  is where the `#N/A` would be.
- `Input Sheet Name` -> `Electricalinput`
  is the sheet name that would be updated.
- `Copy Cols From(Disp)` -> `B:D`
  the columns that would be copied over
- Similar to d but this is where sata would be copied to
  But at the moment the code doesn't use this and just pastes into first available cell in col B

---

Here's the code I attempted, let me know of any suggestions or alterations that would make it easier to use.

```
function cleanComponentList(curSS) {

  Logger.log("Init script cleanComponentList 'Department_List'")  
  curSS = curSS || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var deptListStart = curSS.getRangeByName("Department_List")
  if(deptListStart==null){
    Logger.log("This script cannot be used without the named range 'Department_List'")
    return
  }

  var dept = deptListStart.offset(1,0)
  while( ! dept.isBlank() ){

    Logger.log("Started processing " + dept.getDisplayValue() + " Dept.")

    //Get Department Sheet
    var deptSht = curSS.getSheetByName(dept.offset(0,1).getValue())

    //Get Column that has Action Summary in department sheet
    var actSummCol=deptSht.getRange(2, 1)  
    //Get Department Input Sheet (Target Sheet where we need to copy the final values to
    var deptInputSht = curSS.getSheetByName(dept.offset(0,2).getValue())    

    //Find column with the "Column Header"/"Summary" in which we search #N/A
    while( ! (actSummCol.getDisplayValue() === dept.offset(0,3).getDisplayValue())){
      var tmp = actSummCol.getDisplayValue()
      var actColRng = actSummCol.getA1Notation()
      actSummCol=actSummCol.offset(0,1)
    }

    var actSummColAddress = actSummCol.getA1Notation();
    Logger.log("Found key \"" + dept.offset(0,3).getDisplayValue() + "\" for " + dept.getDisplayValue() + " @ " + actSummColAddress)

    var errRows = []
    //Get all rows that have error Action Summary
    var lastRow = deptSht.getLastRow()
    for(nRow=1;nRow<lastRow;nRow++){
      //There should be a better of checking #N/A
      if(actSummCol.offset(nRow,0).getDisplayValue().equals("#N/A")){
        errRows.push(nRow+actSummCol.getRow())
      }
    }
    Logger.log("Got " + errRows.length + " error rows for " + dept.getDisplayValue() + " Dept.")

    //Get Cell where data append should start from.
    var deptInputLastAvailableRow = deptInputSht.getRange("B1")
    while(!deptInputLastAvailableRow.isBlank() || deptInputLastAvailableRow.isPartOfMerge()){
      deptInputLastAvailableRow=deptInputLastAvailableRow.offset(1,0)
    }
    Logger.log(dept.getDisplayValue() + " Dept." + " Input will be updated from " + deptInputLastAvailableRow.getA1Notation())

    //Copy CDE from the filtered rows to Department Input Sheet
    var srcCols=deptSht.getRange(dept.offset(0,4).getDisplayValue())
    //There should be a better way of iterating. for-of throws syntax error!!!
    for(idx in errRows){
      var row = errRows[idx];
      var lc = srcCols.getLastColumn()
      var fc = srcCols.getColumn()
      var errKeyRangeAddress=srcCols.getCell(row,1).getA1Notation() + ":" + srcCols.getCell(row,lc-fc + 1).getA1Notation()
      var errKeyRange=deptSht.getRange(errKeyRangeAddress) 
      errKeyRange.copyTo(deptInputLastAvailableRow)
      deptInputLastAvailableRow=deptInputLastAvailableRow.offset(1,0)
    }
    Logger.log("Copied " + errRows.length + " entries to Sheet \"" + deptInputSht.getName() + "\"")
    Logger.log("Finished Processing " + dept.getDisplayValue() + " Dept.")
    dept=dept.offset(1,0)
  }
}

function onOpen(){
  //Choose which way you want your menu to appear.
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Monitor", [{name:"Clean Up Keys",functionName:"cleanComponentList"}])
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem("Clean Up Keys", "cleanComponentList").addToUi()
}
```

Comment: That is amazing, works perfect. Thank you so much! I need to spend some time understanding what you have done now. Thanks again.

Comment: cool, let me know if you need any help understanding. I've commented the code a bit for you to understand.

Comment: Yes I would have been completely clueless without the comments. Thanks.

Comment: I really like your approach with adding a sheet that the code references, it seems really clean. I would have been trying to put several sheet names into the code itself

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the notes only hard-coded thing is that the data is always copied to input sheets in column B. You can change that too...

Comment: One thing you might want to look at is exception handling if something happens throw a meaningful error back to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple copy script to help you get started.  copyTo is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).  The rest of the commands can be found in the same documentation.

After you've done a few of your own scripts you'll find it a lot easier to make up your own rather than spending all of your time copying scripts.

```
function copyPasteSelectedRows() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg0.getValues();
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      if(vA[i][10]==1)//condition to meet to copy
      {
        var src=sh0.getRange(i+1,1,1,vA[i].length);//source range
        var tar=sh1.getRange(sh1.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,vA[i].length);//target range
        src.copyTo(tar);
      }
    }
}
```

This is Sheet1:

[image]

This is Sheet2 after the copy:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am going to keep experimenting with the info you posted. Thank you.